# How do I replace an existing git repo with a new repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have started to work on a new project and was provided with bitbucket git repository, when I looked on staging server I noticed that the old developer was working on a gitlab repo. I have spoken to him and he says they mirror each other and that I can remove his git repo and use the one provided. Can anyone advise me how to do that. As it's a Drupal site not all of the directory contents are in the repo so I don't want to delete all and start again with just the repo.

Comment: A repo in git is not a server, it's a logical entity of work: Bitbucket has _a copy_ of your repo and you have a copy locally. What you seem to be referring to are your _remotes,_ of which you can have many. Look at https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url

Comment: Hmm. I get the concept, I think. So I have a .git folder which I assume contains indexes/references to all the directories and files in the directory tree managed by the repo. If I reset the remote how does that effect the files that are physically there? They are not just part of another remote, they are there.

Comment: That depends on what you do with it afterward. Git is by its nature a _distributed_ VCS. The intent being that I can push from my workstation to my colleagues workstation directly, without needing to go through a central server. Keeping this in mind, you can just switch your `origin` (not a special name, just a convention), to your Bitbucket repo's URL and remove gitlab's. Now when you push/pull, you'll update from and to Bitbucket. That's all.

Comment: You may also find this useful https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes You'll possibly run into "remote tracking branch" issues once you make this switch. Hust search the error you get. There are tonnes of resources to help with that. Your git version will also be relevant at that point, so note that as well (`git --version`) when looking for a solution.